# Could not append multiple image files in a PDF

Tags: python-3.x, image, pdf

I know there are answers regarding this question, but hear me out.

I am currently trying to make PDF out of .jpg files using `img2pdf` in python, but instead of appending the files to PDF it overwrites the already existing pages from the PDF.

Here's the code

```
import os,img2pdf

os.chdir("/home/aditya/Desktop")#images are inside desktop

root, dir, files = list(os.walk(os.getcwd()))[0]#files contains the 
                                                 list of all names of all .jpg file
                                                 which I want to convert into PDF

with open("pdf_file.pdf","ab") as f:#PDF file is set to append
    for img_file in files:
        with open(img_file,"rb") as im_file:#read bytes from the image files
            f.write(img2pdf.convert(im_file))#this line overwrites the exisiting
                                              pages in the pdf despite the fact that 
                                              I have set it to #append
```

Any reason for this? Is there special attribute I need to pass?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`img2pdf.convert` does not convert image by image. It either does a single image or all at once

```
img2pdf.convert(list of images )
```

```
with open("pdf_file.pdf","ab") as f: #Open a pdf 
     f.write(img2pdf.convert(files)) #convert all the images and write bytes
```